# what this `^` mean here in solr

Tags: solr, search-engine

I am confuse her but i want to clear my doubt. I think it is stupid question but i want to know.
Use a TokenFilter that outputs two tokens (one original and one lowercased) for each input token. For queries, the client would need to expand any search terms containing upper case characters to two terms, one lowercased and one original. The original search term may be given a boost, although it may not be necessary given that a match on both terms will produce a higher score.

```
text:NeXT ==> (text:NeXT^10 OR text:next)
```

what this `^` mean here .

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook#Relevancy_and_Case_Matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is giving a boost (making it more important) to the value NeXT versus next in this query. From the wiki page you linked to *"The original search term may be given a boost, although it may not be necessary given that a match on both terms will produce a higher score."*

For more on Boosting please see the [Boosting Ranking Terms](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook#Boosting_Ranking_Terms) section in your the [Solr Relevancy Cookbook](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyCookbook). This [Slide Deck about Boosting](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/06/01/a-practical-approach-to-boosting-documents-with-solrlucene/) from the [Lucene Revolution Conference](http://lucenerevolution.org) earlier this year, also contains good information on how boosting works and how to apply it to various scenarios.

**Edit1:**
For more information on the boost values (the number after the ^), please refer to the following:

- [Lucene Score Boosting](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/scoring.html#Score%20Boosting)
- [Lucene Similarity Implementation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html)

**Edit2:**
The value of the boost influences the score/relevancy of an item returned from the search results.

1. `(term:NeXT^10 term:next)` - Any documents matching `term:NeXT` will be scored higher/more relevant in this query because they have a boost value of 10 applied.
2. `(term:NeXT^10 term:Next^5 term:next)` - Any documents matching `term:NeXT` will be scored the highest (because of highest boost value), any documents matching `term:Next` will be scored lower than `term:NeXT`, but higher than `term:next`.

Comment: but what number behind the ^ means

Comment: can uh explain in simple language , i am not able to understand by links